# Downloaded file missing extension

Tags: android

I'm accessing a website to download some files but once the file is downloaded the extension (.zip, etc) is missing.
Project API 21 (Android 5.0.1).

```
private void execute(final Context context) {
    Intent service = null;
    while ((service = queue.peek()) != null) {
        if (running == null) {
            service = queue.remove();

            final Bundle extras = service.getExtras();
            final String url = extras.getString(DownloaderService.KEY_URL);
            final String title = extras.getString(DownloaderService.KEY_TITLE);
            final String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            final File parentDir = new File(Constants.WEB_DIR, title);
            if (!parentDir.exists())
                parentDir.mkdirs();
            final File file = new File(parentDir, (title == null ? filename : title));
            //Log.d("OUTPUTFILE: ", parentDir + "/" + filename); 
            final ProgressNotification notification = new ProgressNotification(context, file);
            notification.createWaiting(title == null ? filename : title);

            context.startService(service);
            running = service;
            Log.d(Constants.LOG, "download started");
            Log.d(Constants.LOG, "running downloads: " + running);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me please?

The directory and file are there and I can execute the file using the Android installer but just the file extension is missing.

Comment: You use the title as file name if there is one. I guess, the title does not have an extension.

Comment: Hi Henry good hint but if i change to "final File file = new File(parentDir + "/" + filename);"
"notification.createWaiting(filename);" it still doesn`t work.

Comment: When you set a breakpoint at 'final String url=...', does url contain the file name and extension when that line is executed?

Comment: as an aside, check out the built in DownloadManager at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html as opposed to DownloaderService...

Comment: @Melquiades
Looks fine to me, here is the logcat:
12-20 19:57:30.055: D/OUTPUTFILE:(21043): http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/downloader/app/files/testfile_web.com.apk

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the mime type being sent by the server from where you are retrieving the file?

If the original storing mechanism did not include a mimetype with storage it may have been coerced to be application/octet stream - thinking it is binary data.  This is what happens in s3 for example when you upload a file without a mimetype property set - or you somehow munge it in the upload process.

When you then access the content uri you would get a file that may be interpreted by the downloading system as being ambiguous.  This can lead to all kinds of problems like with the [mime type map](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html) returning an empty string as the extension when the mime types are ambiguous.

[Good information about mime types and their configurations.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types)

[You could also add the step to guess the mime type from the stream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream(java.io.InputStream)) - as a safeguard.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself, the bug was somewhere else, here is the correct code:

```
@Override
public void onStart(final Intent intent, final int startId) {
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    final String username = extras.getString(KEY_USERNAME);
    final String password = extras.getString(KEY_PASSWORD);
    final String url = extras.getString(DownloaderService.KEY_URL);
    final String title = extras.getString(KEY_TITLE);
    final String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    final File parentDir = new File(Constants.WEB_DIR title);
    if (!parentDir.exists())
        parentDir.mkdirs();
    final File file = new File(parentDir + "/" + filename); <---- solved
    notification = new ProgressNotification(DownloaderService.this, file);
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                download();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                Log.e(Constants.LOG, e.getMessage(), e);
                parentDir.delete();
            }
            stopSelf();
        }
```

But thx guys for putting me on the right track.